# How can I complete missing values in time series

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, missing-data

I have the dataset which columns are
`date`, `time_id`, `num_travel`. such as

```
date       time_id  num_travel
02/25/2013       6        23
02/25/2013       7        20
02/25/2013       8        55
02/25/2013       9        89
02/25/2013       10       150
02/25/2013       11       100

...
02/27/2013       1        20
...
```

`time_id` means which hour in that date.
`num_travel` means a number of travel.

`time_id` range is 1~24 for 1 day, but always lost the 1~6 randomly for everyday. How can I add the rows with `num_travel` (initialize this value to 0) that such as

```
 03/24/2013     2      0   # (the data not exist in dataset, but need to be added)
```

Because the dataset lost the `time_id` from 1 to 6 randomly, it is really hard to build these rows. I need some help in R to do the data cleansing.

Comment: I think `complete` will help you from `tidyr`. Something like `complete(df, date, time_id, fill = list(num_travel = 0))`

Comment: should the function be like this?                                                         
```complete(data, data$date, data$time_id, fill = list(num_travel = 0))``` it doesn't wok like that

Comment: Try `new_data <- complete(data, date, time_id, fill = list(num_travel = 0))`, `new_data` is your output dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to have understood correctly your question so I give you two answers. I just use basic R.

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(date = mdy(c(rep("02/25/2013", 6), "02/27/2013")),
                 time_id = c(6:11, 1),
                 num_travel = c(23, 20, 55, 89, 150, 100, 20))

want_to_add <- data.frame(date = mdy("03/27/2013"),
                          time_id = 2,
                          num_travel = 0)
```

The first answer if you only need to add few lines :

```
rbind(df, want_to_add)
```

If you have a lot of missing data and you want a pseudo complet database with 0, you can built one complet with only 0 for the variable `num_travel` and then add what you already know about `num_travel` :

```
# vector of Date
date_start <- as.POSIXct("2013-02-25 01:00:00", tz = "GMT")
date_end <- as.POSIXct("2013-03-27 01:00:00", tz = "GMT")

Date <- seq(date_start, date_end, by="hour")

# complet data set with 0 for num_travel
df_res <- data.frame(date = as.Date(Date), time_id = hour(Date) + 1, num_travel = 0)

# add what you know 
df_res[paste(df_res$date, df_res$time_id) %in% paste(df$date, df$time_id), ]$num_travel = df$num_travel
```

Comment: the total date from 2013/02/25 to 2013/03/24 contains 672 rows, and the data contains 553 rows, so all the c(data$date, data$time_id) should be included in the 675 rows of the date. but there is an error which shows that 
```There are 553 rows in the replacement data, but the data has 548 rows.``` But the number of  ```df_res``` is 672 rows. How does it calculate that the data has 548 rows.

Comment: Clearly all your decomposed date should be in the date built thanks to the code above. Are you sure that all your date are in the same date format than the object : `df_res$date`. With the `%in%` you compare character, so it needs the exact same date format. You can use `ydm` function of lubridate. I hope it will help you. Tell me if not

Comment: Thank you so much, your method works well. The reason why my code works unwell is that there must be something wrong with the function as.POSIXct. It changes 5 rows of data in 2013/02/24 which should be 2015/02/25. I use  as.Date instead of as.POSIXct, and the code works well.